# Manually setup application release versions in Azure Dev Ops without going through whole pipeline process?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm new to Azure Dev Ops. I'm small 1-man developer producing small apps. I'm using ADO for the versioning + repo, Feature + Bug task creation + Boards systems. Also, future limited collaboration. I really don't need the full build and deployment features of the pipelines system. Any public releases will be built locally and deployed manually, infrequently.

I'm looking for a way to register my Feature/Bug cards against Release versions (e.g. placing stretch-goal features against future release versions, or bug fixes against increases of minor build increases). However, this seems to be linked to the Releases system which seems to be inexorably linked with the whole complicated pipelines system? I'd just like a way to choose the build version from a drop-down in the task card.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What I understand is that you don't use DevOps pipeline in the process of building and deploying your application. One of the uses of work items is to support work tracking. We can track the progress of the work by linking work items to the build or release pipeline. If you don't use pipeline, this feature cannot be achieved. Or do you just want a field that displays the build version in the work item? If so, you can use [inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) and customize the work item.

Comment: Your understanding is right. I build and deploy manually away from ADO. But, what I want is to be able to register my Features and Work items against prospective future Build Versions (I guess they'd be pseudo build versions as I wouldn't be actually building them in ADO). I took a look at that link and just couldn't tally it with what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks anyway.